# MySQL query with matching and sum - League Table

Tags: mysql

I have 5 tables:

- Players (id, name, team_id)
- Teams (id, name)
- Results (id, game_id, player.id, position)
- Games (id, location)
- Score (position, score)

as [follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5SJ1.png)

[image]

I want to make a league table like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKXnV.png)

[image]

I am confused how to sum up the scores for each player. This is my code so far:

```
SELECT Players.name, Teams.name, Results.position FROM Players
INNER JOIN Teams ON Players.team_id = Teams.id
JOIN Results ON Player.id = Results.player_id
JOIN Scores ON Results.position = Scores.scores
```

Any idea?

Comment: where did table `Drivers` come from ?

Comment: I made a mistake, it should be Players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list all the players (whether they appear on the results table or not) you have to use a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT p.name player_name,t.name team_name,SUM(COALESCE(s.score,0)) as total_score
FROM players p
INNER JOIN teams t ON t.id = p.team_id
LEFT JOIN results r ON p.id = r.player_id
LEFT JOIN scores s ON s.position = r.position
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY total_score desc
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Players.name, 
       Teams.name,
       sum(Results.position * Scores.scores) as scores
FROM Players
JOIN Teams ON Players.team_id = Teams.id
JOIN Results ON Player.id = Results.player_id
JOIN Scores ON Results.position = Scores.scores
GROUP BY Players.name, Teams.name
```

Comment: what if the player(e.g id.11) never appears on the table 'result' ?how to retrieve all players' score?

Comment: Use a `left join` instead of a normal `join`